How can I expand horizontally an object in flet?
I want to expand a flet(Python) container which is in a Column which is in a Row, that fills all the space horizontally.
Maybe get the page width. But then I want to publish into Android.
Really hope you can help me.
I'm a newbie in flet.
Thanks in advance.
